# How to get the left margin of a centered view in android?

Tags: android, xml

I have view that is centered in xml by android:layout_centerHorizontal="true". How do I get the leftMargin of it, so I can align other views with it?

I tried using getLayoutParams on the centered view but it didn't work. It seems to report a leftMargin of 0.

I also tried to compute the leftMargin with (screenWidth-view width)/2, but it gives a slightly higher value than expected. More specifically, this is my code:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight  = size.y;

    TextView button1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
    button1.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=102;
    params.width=114;
    params.topMargin =0;
    button1.setLayoutParams(params);
    params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button1.getLayoutParams();
    int leftMargin = params.leftMargin;

    TextView button2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button2.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=102;
    params.width=114;
    params.leftMargin =leftMargin;
    params.topMargin =102;
    button2.setLayoutParams(params);

    TextView button3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    params=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button3.getLayoutParams();
    params.height=102;
    params.width=114;
    params.leftMargin =(screenWidth-114)/2;
    params.topMargin =204;
    button3.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Button1 is centered in xml.
Button2 is left-aligned, not centered.
Button3 is more or less centered, but slightly to the right.

So,

1) how do I get the left margin of a view centered in xml?

2) how do I center (exactly) a view in code? Does getDefaultDisplay reports an higher width than the real screen width?

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_alignLeft` or `android:layout_alignStart` ?  You can use this with the views that you wish to align with the centered view by specifying its id.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly ask the layout to have the views aligned. For example,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centered_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Random text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/centered_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Top Button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/centered_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottom Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
To get the relative offset of the centered view, this might suffice:

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "top: " + textView.getTop() + " left: " + textView.getLeft());
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

See:

[View.getTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29) and [View.getLeft()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29)

Comment: Ok, this works and it is useful. However, it doesn't quite answer my question. If I want another view to be, let's say 200 pixels to right of the centered view, I need to know the left margin of the centered view. So, how do I get it from the view itself or how do I compute it?

Comment: You mean you want the view right before the centered view? You could use `android:layout_toLeftOf` or  `android:layout_toRightOf` and set some margin?

Comment: No, I need to know the exact value of the left margin of the centered view, so that I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: I've added something, please check if that meets your requirements

Comment: I've added int leftMargin = button1.getLeft() but I still get 0. I suspect that if we don't set it otherwise, the leftMargin of a centered object is 0. That is, centering an object horizontally doesn't change it's leftMargin. So the question remains, maybe with different terms: How to determine the distance from the left side of a centered view to the left side of the screen?

Comment: getLeft() and methods such as these only work after they've been laid out properly, you should either perform these inside onGlobalLayout() (otherwise they remain 0) or initialize some fields there and do what you wish to with those values.